# Image not drawing into the canvas using base64 string data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html5-canvas

I tried to draw an image into `canvas` using base64 data. Transparent canvas appears on the screen without image.

**HTML code**

```
<canvas id="c" style ="position: absolute; border: solid; border-color: #000000;"></canvas>
```

**Code behind**

```
byte[] imgBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgBytes));
String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
String src = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}\"", base64String);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:drawMap(" + src + "); ", true);
```

**JavaScript**

```
var htmlCanvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = htmlCanvas.getContext("2d");

function drawMap(imgdata) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
  image.src = imgdata;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, your context is stored as `context` but you're calling `ctx.drawImage` - you need to have either `context.drawImage` or `var ctx = htmlCanvas.getContext("2d");`

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your JavaScript. Here is a working example:

```js
var htmlCanvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = htmlCanvas.getContext("2d");

function drawMap(imgdata) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
  image.src = imgdata;
}

drawMap("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAFUlEQVR42mNk+M9Qz0AEYBxVSF+FAAhKDveksOjmAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
```

```html
<canvas id="c" style="position: absolute; border: solid; border-color: #000000;"></canvas>
```

Also you must enclose the image data string in quotes when you're passing it to the `drawMap()` function and don't proceed it with `javascript:`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
             "Javascript", "drawMap('" + src + "');", true);
```

Comment: i have base64 string which is too long i don't know how to pass it as a parameter

Comment: it has 26982 character length

Comment: Yes, images produce long base64 strings, but that's fine. I've already shown you how to pass, see the last line in my answer. Do you need to use `canvas`? If not, you can write it directly to an HTML `<img>` tag.

Comment: when i trace the line in debugger i found that the characters are missing

Comment: I understand that you're using `canvas`, but I was asking if have to use `canvas`.

Comment: i can't use directly image tag because i am going to draw areas over the canvas

Comment: That's the answer to my question, you need to `canvas`.  OK, and what characters do you see missing in debugger?

Comment: half of the base64 string character are missing

Comment: Are they missing in random sports, or continuously at the end of the string?

Comment: continuously at the end

Comment: What is the first character that is missing? Pay attention, this is important.

Comment: i'm not sure from which character it missing but u guess  it misses the character from coma i.e. ,

Comment: The comma is right at the beginning, so if it's missing, then it's missing everything. trace the line again in the debugger and compare the string to the original to see the part that's missing and let me know the first missing character.

Comment: when i resize the canvas to size of image after that the image then image is not drawing to the canvas